# Using filters on Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Please help to find the reason of error. 
Have two objects which ones returning from my view :

```
def managment_users_form(request):

    users = User.objects.all()
    usersinfo = usersinfo_model.objects.all()
    count_objects = users.count()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.username
        context = {
            'users': users,
            'usersinfo': usersinfo,
            'count_objects': count_objects,
        }
        return render(request, 'users.html', context)
    else:
        return redirect('login_form')
```

And on my template I want to make for cycle from first one and filter by id in cycle another one.  First is working well, but second one I'm getting error when try to use filter.

Teamplate

```
{% for user in users %}
<div class="">
    <h4 class="m-b-5">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h4>
        <p class="text-muted">{{ useremp|user_info_filter:user.id }} <span></p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

filter

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='user_info_filter')
def user_info_filter(useremp, id):
    return useremp.filter(user_id=id)
```

Please help to understand the mistake.
Error is : "Invalid filter: 'user_info_filter'"

Comment: Did you add `{% load modulename %}` to your template? Check this doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters

Comment: I tried, but git the next error :

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError at /managment/users/

'user_info_filter' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz

Comment: Did you put `user_info_filter.py` inside app_name/templatetags? and make sure you restart the Django development server (or ensure it restarted itself) every time you modify template tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the filter to settings.py? It's required from 1.9 Django

ex :

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    ],
    'libraries':{
        'filter': 'project_name.templatetags.filter',

    }
},
```